# sunspot solr, rails 3.1.1: Why do my results have the entire db record printed automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I did the standard procedure in setting up Sunspot Solr for my rails app but when I print the results, I get the entire db record printed automatically.

Here is my results.html.erb:

```
<%= @users.each do |result| %>
    <%= link_to "#{result.first_name}", user_path(result) %>
<% end %>
```

The view rendered is:

```
Test [#<User id: 38, first_name: "Test", last_name: "Test", email: "test@test.com", encrypted_password: "b519f1c58f8f5b9fffa0ada91ac7ca8316ebb8f8cec548404b8...", salt: "7f6287c48f49ac0a55c2cdc00803caaaa463c3b5efb88b57f40...", created_at: "2011-11-28 07:00:32", updated_at: "2011-11-28 07:00:32">
```

Can you please tell me how can I get rid of the hash and just be able to display the first name?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As answered below, your `<%= @users.each… %>` is printing the return value of `@users.each` which is the entire `@users` array. If you copied that `<%=` from a Sunspot tutorial somewhere, you should report it to the author so they can correct the bug.

Comment: No I wrote it myself, it was my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take out the `=` at `<%= @users.each do |result| %>`

so instead

```
<% @users.each do |result| %>
    <%= link_to "#{result.first_name}", user_path(result) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Such a silly mistake and the worst part not realizing it, LOL. Thank you very much. Problem solved